# Garbage value being passed while Summing up Array of Long Long integers

Tags: c++

I am learning to code in C++. I came across a problem that requires making a function to add up very large number and return the sum. I see a mysterious behavior. When I print the number `veryBigSum` inside the function `aVeryBigSum` before returning the value, it works properly.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

long long aVeryBigSum(int n, vector <long long> ar) {

    long long veryBigSum;

    for(vector<long long>::iterator it = ar.begin(); it != ar.end(); ++it )
        veryBigSum += *it;

    cout << veryBigSum << "\n"; 
    return veryBigSum;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<long long> ar(n);

    for(int ar_i = 0; ar_i < n; ar_i++){
        cin >> ar[ar_i];
    }

    long long result = aVeryBigSum(n, ar);
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Input for the above is:

```
5
1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005
```

Output for the above is:

```
5000000015
5000000015
```

But when I don't print the number inside the `aVeryBigSum` function, the `cout` statement inside `main` displays some garbage value.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

long long aVeryBigSum(int n, vector <long long> ar) {

    long long veryBigSum;

    for(vector<long long>::iterator it = ar.begin(); it != ar.end(); ++it )
        veryBigSum += *it;

    return veryBigSum;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<long long> ar(n);

    for(int ar_i = 0; ar_i < n; ar_i++){
        cin >> ar[ar_i];
    }

    long long result = aVeryBigSum(n, ar);
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Input for the above is:

```
5
1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005
```

Output for the above is:

```
5004197743
```

Can someone please explain to me why is this happening? I mean, how does printing a value affect passing of the variable between to function?

Comment: Initialize `veryBigSum` to `0` before calculating sum.

Comment: I suspect you are seeing symptoms of UB since `veryBigSum` is not initialized.

Comment: @CinCout Then is this behavior happening because of compiler optimization?

Comment: @sohnryang No compiler optimization. This is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: A warning about `#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <vector> using namespace std;` The first line is a g++ internal implementation library that is not intended to be directly included. It includes the entire standard library. That's a lot of stuff you don't need. This also means that the second line does absolutely nothing. <vector> has already been included. The third line places everything in the `std` namespace into the global namespace. Now all that stuff you don't need can easily get in your way, and when it does the errors are bizarre and often barely comprehensible. Use with caution.

Comment: @CinCout Then why does the function returns the right result when printed the value?

Comment: @sohnryang One cannot justify UB.

Comment: Quoting from one of my answers: *"As aptly as it is named, it is not defined, meaning you may get the expected result or you may not. What you should do is not rely on such results since they are not well-defined. You may feel lucky for getting expected results, but believe me, it's a trap!"* https://stackoverflow.com/a/39910584/2912665

Comment: Invoking UB is probably the most feared thing a you can do in a program because you might not know the error is there until it blows up a few [billion dollars of rocket ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_(spacecraft)#Launch_failure), [makes you look very bad in front of your boss](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73wMnU7xbwE) or steers an airliner full of people into the side of a mountain. Thank god I don't have an example for that one.

Comment: I thought that including <bits/stdc++.h> should help in initializing everything to 0. But I guess it does not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your accumulator:

```
long long veryBigSum = 0;
```

It is only by chance (*undefined behavior*) that you are getting the right answer some times.

Comment: Ohh thanks. Rookie mistake. I will keep this in mind. Thanks a lot.